# YouTube Objective-C API video url from playlist item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, youtube-api

I am having trouble getting the video url for a YouTube video. I can retrieve the playlist items with a thumbnail and title but I can't get the actual video url.

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];

service.APIKey = @"API Key";

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"snippet,contentDetails"];
query.playlistId = @"playlist ID";
query.maxResults = 50;

GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                   if (error == nil)
                                   {
                                       GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;
                                       for (GTLYouTubeSearchResult *item in products)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"%@", item.snippet);
                                           NSString *dictionary = [item.snippet JSONValueForKey:@"videoId"];
                                           GTLYouTubeThumbnailDetails *thumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails;
                                           GTLYouTubeThumbnail *thumbnail = thumbnails.high;
                                           NSString *thumbnailString = thumbnail.url;
                                           if (thumbnailString != nil)
                                           {
                                               [self.thumbnailsArray addObject:thumbnailString];
                                               [self.thumbnailTitleArray addObject:item.snippet.title];
                                               //[self.videos addObject:video];
                                               NSLog(@"id: %@", dictionary);
                                           }

                                       }
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                   }
                                   [self.tableView reloadData];
                               }];
```

Does anyone know how to get the video url using the YouTube API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want only videos in your search result you should set [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) = video.
In your code:

```
query.playlistId = @"playlist ID";
query.maxResults = 50;
query.type = @"video";
```

You need to add "id" into part. Your query call will be:

```
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"id,snippet,contentDetails"];
```

and in response you can get video id with [id.videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#id.videoId). So in your code it will be:

```
NSString *videoId = item.identifier.videoId;
```

Once you have the id, you can plug it in:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={VIDEO ID HERE}
```

Comment: Worked great! I just had to change item.id.videoId to item.identifier.videoId. Thank you for the reply! :D

Answer (score 0):

The [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) in the v3 API does not provide a URL. What you can do instead is to append the video ID to a string. Play page URLs tend to be of the format:

```
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={VIDEO ID HERE}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :D I am also having trouble getting the videoId. It is returning null. I can see the videoId inside the resourceId JSON object.